# Создание jar архива

Tags: java, jar, компиляция

При создании можно ли указать `Main-Class`? А то мне приходится добавлять манифест в jar вручную.

Comment: А чем ты jar собираешь?

Comment: В консоле... яром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если собираешь ant'ом, то вот простой `build.xml`:

```
<project name="name" default="jar">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.HelloWorld"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
 <project>
```

Запуск:

`ant
ant jar`

Comment: А без ant?)

Answer (score 2):

Что-то в таком духе

```
echo Main-Class: my.pkg.HelloWorld> mymanifest
jar cvfm HelloWorld.jar mymanifest -C build/classes .
```

Вот только не понятно, зачем так мучать себя? Почему не использовать ant, как тут предлагалось?

Comment: Просто для знания) Ну почти так я и делал...

Answer (score 2):

Под мавеном я собираю с помощью вот такого плагина:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass> your.main.class</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>    
                        <shadedClassifierName>executable</shadedClassifierName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Это особое искусство сделать простую задачу настолько сложной, чтобы её было не выполнить по памяти, а только копипастом из гугла.

Comment: можно подумать, что все помки Вы пишете с нуля и "по памяти"??

Comment: В этом проблема помок как таковых: их почти нельзя написать по памяти, если не заниматься только этим целыми днями. Комплишн, поддерживаемый идеей конечно помогает, но всё равно не всё подсказывает и нельзя всё упомнить. Не говоря уже о вечных ограничениях плагинов.